# Как сделать так, что бы Preloader показывался один раз?

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

Реализовал на сайте Preloader, но затем столкнулся с проблемой, при каждом обновлении страницы, Preloader снова начинает грузиться, как сделать так, что бы он грузился, к примеру, только при первом открытии сайта с момента открытия браузера!? Искал решение через sessionStorage, но столкнулся с проблемой, что Preloader зациклился, помогите разобраться, вот пример кода:

```
if(!sessionStorage.getItem("load")){
  sessionStorage.setItem("load", true);
  $(window).on('load', function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
    var $preloader = $('#page-preloader'),
        $spinner   = $preloader.find('.spinner');
    $spinner.fadeOut();
    $preloader.delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
    }, 1000)
  });
}
```

Comment: Это очень странный вопрос. Зачем вам вообще нужен прелоадер в таком случае? Сам по себе, прелоадер нужен скорее SPA приложениям, а не сайтам.

Answer (score -1):

```
window.addEventListener('load', load)
// $(window).on('load', load)

function load() {
    let div = document.createElement('div')
    div.innerHTML = '!sessionStorage'
    if (sessionStorage) {
        if (!sessionStorage.getItem('load')) {
            sessionStorage.setItem('load', 'true')
            div.innerHTML = 'preloader'
            // preloader()
        } else {
            div.innerHTML = 'preloader else'
        }
    }
    document.body.appendChild(div)
}

function preloader() {
    var $preloader, $spinner
    // --
    $preloader = $('#page-preloader')
    $spinner = $preloader.find('.spinner')
    // --
    $spinner.fadeOut()
    $preloader.delay(350).fadeOut('slow')
}
```

---

```
interface Storage {
        readonly length: number;
        clear(): void;
        getItem(key: string): string | null;
        key(index: number): string | null;
        removeItem(key: string): void;
        setItem(key: string, data: string): void; // <--- !!!
        [key: string]: any;
        [index: number]: string;
    }
```

---

непонятно что там у автора не работает, оставлю будущим поколениям.

в случае старых браузеров или двух разных доменов
https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie